# play framework listen on localhost

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

Is it possible to start play framework 2.3 on localhost ? I have tried

```
./activator run -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.port=9007

./activator run -Dhttp.address=localhost -Dhttp.port=9007 # From
```

another stackoverflow thread
    ./activator start -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.port=9007

But nothing works everytime I am receiving

```
[info] play - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9007
```

related thread [Force Play Framework to listen on localhost only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16370704/force-play-framework-to-listen-on-localhost-only)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ProductionConfiguration) provided by Play Framework the way you're going at it only works for Netty based instances of Play. I presume you are using Akka-Http, if you're not however, please report this as a bug to the Play Framework team.

You might also want to read up on [this](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/HTTPServer), it covers on how to set Play Framework up to work behind a proxy such as Nginx or Apache.

One last thing, it is generally recommended to only expose the absolute necessary ports to the outside internet, preventing attackers from exploiting possible weak points in your system. I advice you, doesn't matter if you get this in working order or not, to also install some good IPTables software on your box and block the port your local, behind the firewall, Play instance is running on.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of:
`./activator run -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1 -Dhttp.port=9007`

reverse the arguments ("-D" option before "run"):

`activator -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1 run`

```
--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---
[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /127.0.0.1:9007
(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do `activator "run 9007"` (assuming `activator` is in your `PATH`, which is the norm).

See also:

- [How do I change the default port (9000) that Play uses when I execute the "run" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205067/how-do-i-change-the-default-port-9000-that-play-uses-when-i-execute-the-run)
- [How to change HTTP port that Play2 is listening on](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9941689/how-to-change-http-port-that-play2-is-listening-on)

Comment: it changes port , but not host.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

./activator "run 9007"

you can access your application through localhost by this. you can write any port you want in place of 9007

Comment: it listens on 0.0.0.0 by default . And I need really 127.0.0.1

Comment: Loopback address is a special IP number (127.0.0.1) that is designated for the software loopback interface of a machine. try this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/20778887/1478261

Comment: 0.0.0.0 means that my site is accessible from outside, 127.0.0.1 means that only local services can connect to it. My play framework is behind ngnix proxy, and I want to avoid direct access from internet to play - I can do it with iptables but seems to be a more simple way.

Comment: Then I think IP table is a better option.