# Specifying Play 2.0 port with "dist"

Tags: java, playframework, sbt

I'm creating a packaged project using`dist` and am trying to modify the generated `start` script to run the app on port `9001`.

Here is what is generated:

```
exec java $* -cp "`dirname $0`/lib/*" play.core.server.NettyServer `dirname $0`
```

Here is what I tried, which doesn't seem to work.

```
exec java $* -Dhttp.port=9001 -cp "`dirname $0`/lib/*" play.core.server.NettyServer `dirname $0`
```

Any ideas?

I've also tried specifying `http.port=9001` in `application.conf` with no avail. It was **very easy** to do this in Play 1.2.X, seems a step backward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After running `play dist` and then extracting the generated bundle, you can start Play 2 on a different port by running:

```
./start -Dhttp.port=5432
```

Or if you would rather edit the `start` script you can update it to be:

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

exec java $* -Dhttp.port=5432 -cp "`dirname $0`/lib/*" play.core.server.NettyServer `dirname $0`
```

And then run:

```
./start
```

Comment: So you want to modify the start script rather than pass a parameter to the start script?

Comment: I tried passing a parameter to the generated script. It's not the target/start script. It's the start script generated after running play dist.

Comment: Sorry.  Usually I use `play stage`.  I've updated the instructions for using `play dist` and tested them on Linux.  If this doesn't work for you, maybe it's a bug in your version of Play.  Or an OS specific bug.  In that case let me know what version of Play and what OS you are using.

Comment: BTW, the `$*` in the script just takes all of the command params and passed them to the `java` command.  So if specifying `-Dhttp.port` doesn't work as a param to `start` then it's not going to work to modify the command.

Comment: Right, I figured that. Hmmm. Something is fishy here. Let me get back to you!

Comment: @JamesWard Is this supposed to work in Play 2.2(+) as well? I know `start` is replaced with my application name but if I set `-Dhttp.port=80` it still listens on port 9000. (No errors, Windows 8, play 2.2.2)

Comment: It actually looks like it does still work on Linux which is actually all I need.

Comment: Here is a better answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205067/how-do-i-change-the-default-port-9000-that-play-uses-when-i-execute-the-run/8206747#8206747