# Is it possible to have two different versions (1.2.5 and 2.0.4) of play framework on the same server?

Tags: mongodb, playframework, version

I don't find anything on this problem... I have two play framework apps. The first is developed with play framework 1.2.5, the second with 2.0.4. I want to know if it's possible to have these two versions on the same server.

I have a mongoDb server and I would keep this server available only in local.

So, What can you advise me?

Thanks very much !

Answer (score 2):

You just run the two versions on different ports. In Play 1.x, the setting in `application.conf` is

```
http.port=9001
```

For Play 2.x, it's a bit more complicated, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205067/how-do-i-change-the-default-port-9000-that-play-uses-when-i-execute-the-run). But you only really need to change the port of one installation.

If you would want to serve both instances on port 80, you'd need to stick a proxy in front of both of them.

Comment: Ok but how to distinguish the command "play" between the two versions ?

Comment: Don't put them on the `path`, but call them explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

If it's unix system you can create a symlinks for both versions do something like this (step by step, make sure that you're not devasting your system :) ):

```
bash#: which play
/usr/bin/play

# use path returned with previous 'which'
bash#: cd /usr/bin
bash#: sudo cp play play1
bash#: sudo ln -s /full/path/to/your/play-2.0.x/play play20x
```

So you'll be able to start your app like this:

```
cd /path/to/play2app
play20x run
```

or

```
cd /path/to/play1app
play1 run
```

For running both on port 80 use frontend HTTP server.