# How do I change the default port (9000) that Play uses when I execute the “debug run” command?

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.0

I usually start my Play 2.0 application with `play "~run 8991"` to run my application on port 8991 instead of the default port 9000, as described in [this other Stack Overflow question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205067/how-do-i-change-the-default-port-9000-that-play-uses-when-i-execute-the-run)

But how can I change the default port when I want to *debug* my application?
`play "debug run 8991"`* still uses port 9000; the `8991` will get ignored.

(Note to close voters, this is NOT a dupe of the linked question. That one says nothing about debugging.)

Comment: It's not a duplicate, as the answer there does work only with `run` and not with `debug run`.

Comment: Yeah, this is not a duplicate.

Comment: I voted to leave closed.  The answer in the other thread covers many related cases.  "Debug" is just another slight variation and you should comment on the other answer for it to be included.  This does not warrant a separate question.

Comment: @JasonMArcher It really does. It is a different syntax that is not reflected in the other question's answer as thorough as it is

Comment: After I made my comment, I added to the answer in the referenced thread.  So it does now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run in debug mode with the http listener on port `8991`, run:

```
play debug "run 8991"
```

Comment: Thanks again. I didn't know that it would be so easy.