# Debugging play framework, different port

Tags: playframework, playframework-2.2

I want to debug play 2 application. My port 9000 is occupied by a system process. How do I specify a different port when launching "`play debug run`"?

Comment: Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205067/how-do-i-change-the-default-port-9000-that-play-uses-when-i-execute-the-run

Comment: not a duplicate, since debug mode was not covered there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this - `play debug "run 9001"`

Answer (score 0):

The link posted in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21263619/debugging-play-framework-different-port#comment32036397_21263619) explains how to change the port that Play's HTTP server runs on. As for the port that the debugger listens on, that's hardcoded in Play's startup script:

#### play

```
if test "$1" = "debug"; then
  JPDA_PORT="9999"
  shift      
fi
```

#### play.bat

```
:setDebug
set JPDA_PORT=9999
shift
set additionalArgs=%additionalArgs:*debug=%
```