# Assigning Play a default Address to port

Tags: http, playframework, port

I want that when someone requests a website without specifying the port (9000), 
It will redirect them to the play framework.
Currently the situation is that I need to enter : `somesite.com:9000`
I want that you'd only enter: `somesite.com` and you'd get to the play framework.

How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the default port (9000) that Play uses when I execute the "run" command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205067/how-do-i-change-the-default-port-9000-that-play-uses-when-i-execute-the-run)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per the [documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation) provided by Play, you can use the `http.port` argument on application startup to specify which port to listen on. Binding to port 80 (the standard HTTP port) will allow you to get to your application via domain name alone:

```
-Dhttp.port=80
```

Note that as of version 2.1, Play applications can be configured to serve content over HTTPS. In this case you can use the similar `https.port` argument and bind to port 443 (the standard HTTPS port):

```
-Dhttps.port=443
```