# How to configure https with play in production mode version 2.2.1

Tags: https, playframework, playframework-2.2

I am trying to set up https for play 2.2.1.
It successfully works by running:

```
# play -Dhttps.port=9443
# run
```

But then when I do it with

```
# play -Dhttps.port=9443
# dist
```

and unzip the folder and try to run it with the .bat file. However,play does not listen to HTTPS as it did when I used 'play run' ( it only listens to HTTP).

I've tried both

```
# <name>.bat
```

and

```
# <name>.bat -Dhttps.port=9443
```

Am I missing something? I've looked at 
http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ConfiguringHttps
from my understanding 'start' is the name.bat since I am running it in Windows.
Are there any additional configurations/steps I need to take?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: I think it could be a Windows 8 problem because it worked in Linux. I am still interested in finding out if there is a workaround. Please let me know if you know.

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, dev mode uses the environment variable PLAY_OPTS.  In looks like the generated Windows batch file recognizes an environment _OPTS.  My app is called mdash:

```
"%_JAVACMD%" %_JAVA_OPTS% %MDASH_OPTS% -cp "%APP_CLASSPATH%" %APP_MAIN_CLASS% %CMDS%
```

See my answer to this question: [How do I change the default port (9000) that Play uses when I execute the "run" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205067/how-do-i-change-the-default-port-9000-that-play-uses-when-i-execute-the-run/23518524#23518524)