# How to change the http port for play framework 2.4.1?

Tags: playframework-2.0

I come from a play 1.2.7 application and currently getting started with play framework 2.4.1 and scala. For a start I use the activator web ui to manage applications and there I cannot get the application to use a different http port.

I changed the http.port setting in conf/application.conf, but still play 2.4.1 tries to bind to port 9000, which is already in use. The setting I tried is:

```
http.port=7000
```

Any suggestion on how to change the port for a play framework 2.4.1 application that is run via the activator web ui?

Note that as suggested in the linked question I can use

```
./activator "run 7000"
```

in the application itself to have it bind to port 7000. Still my question is how can I get the same behaviour via the activator web ui?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the default port (9000) that Play uses when I execute the "run" command?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205067/how-do-i-change-the-default-port-9000-that-play-uses-when-i-execute-the-run)

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration

Comment: I followed the documentation and added http.port to application.conf, it just doesn't seem to be used. I don't use the play run method right now, but activator's web ui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to build.sbt of your project where `<port>` should be replaced with your desired port number.

build.sbt

```
fork in run := true
javaOptions in run += "-Dhttp.port=<port>"
```

Expected console output in Activator UI on run

```
Setting up Play fork run ... (use Ctrl+D to cancel)

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

p.a.l.c.ActorSystemProvider - Starting application default Akka system: application
p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:<port>

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

Comment: I've tried to do this and it doesn't work. I tried starting it with activator and with sbt, and neither picked up the option

Comment: This solution is solely for starting applications via Activator Web UI (`activator ui`). If you want to change the port when using sbt or activator command line just add `-Dhttp.port=<port>` to your command (e.g. `activator run -Dhttp.port=8080`)

Answer (score 10):

Through the `application.conf` in production:

```
play.server.http.port = 80
```

When you run the application with SBT:

```
PlayKeys.devSettings := Seq("play.server.http.port" -> "80")
```

Using `run` command:

```
$ run 80
```

For more details please refer the below links:

[documentation-Config File](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ConfigFile)

[documentation-Server configuration options](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration#Server-configuration-options)

Comment: It's never too late to give some effort to answer a question!

Answer (score 0):

Just a short note concerning the `run` command (tested with Play! 2.4):

At least on Windows `activator run -Dhttp.port=80` does NOT work, but 
`activator` (hit enter) and then `run -Dhttp.port=80` works

Comment: You'll have to use quotes when passing parameters to activator (or sbt): `activator "run -Dhttp.port=80"`, otherwise each parameter is assumed to be a task and run separately. When running the activator (or sbt) console, you can omit the quotes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
activator "run 9500"
```

in terminal from your project folder.

Answer (score 0):

This command work for me guys:

```
activator "~run 3333"
```