# IntelJ : run 2 applications at the same time using different port

Tags: playframework, sbt

I have two applications that need to be run at the same time. For the first app i use **sbt run** and the app is loaded succesfully and is listening on the port 9000. When i run the second app with **sbt run** i have an error saying : Failed to bind to : /0.0.0.0:9000 and it make sens since it already used by the first app but i still have the same error even when i want to run it on a different port : sbt run 9100. There's a configuration that i should manually do somewhere?

I'm using playFramework

Comment: Which app do you run? Play framework, I suppose?

Comment: Yes i'm using play

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to permanently change the port for some Play application run from sbt, put the following line into your `build.sbt`:

```
play.PlayImport.PlayKeys.playDefaultPort := 9001
```

Alternative ways are listed in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36246022/371804