# How to change the http port for play framework 2.5.9

Tags: playframework, typesafe-activator

How to change the default port from 9000 to 9001 in Play 2.5.9?

Tried following steps

1. Changed http.port = 9001 in application.conf
2. Tried the steps mentioned in this post
    [a link] [How to change the http port for play framework 2.4.1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31157400/how-to-change-the-http-port-for-play-framework-2-4-1)

But this works 
**activator run -Dhttp.port=9001 -Dhttp.address=127.0.0.1**

Can we change it from application.conf instead of specifying port from command line?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In a way, no you can not add HTTP server setting in `application.conf` in reload mode (`activator run`).

In `run` mode by the time the play server starts, your `application.conf` is not resolved yet, but if you use `state` it works fine.

If you want to avoid providing port everytime you run the command, you could add it in `build.sbt` as following.

`PlayKeys.devSettings := Seq("play.server.http.port" -> "9001")`

It is explained [here](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ConfigFile#Using-with-the-run-command)

Comment: Or to override the default port, use e.g. `PlayKeys.playDefaultPort := 9001`

Answer (score 6):

Since version 2.5 you can set the port of your Play application in `application.conf` **but** this settings will only be used when running the application in production mode.

```
play.server {

    # These settings only apply when running in production mode (e.g. when using the stage/dist task)
    # To apply these settings in dev mode see:
    # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ConfigFile#Using-with-the-run-command
    # https://groups.google.com/d/msg/play-framework/-EE28jmb4Uw/MBRQvAhhCwAJ
    # https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ProductionConfiguration
    # ~~~~~
    http {
        address = 127.0.0.1
        port = 9000
    }

    #https {
    #   address = 127.0.0.1
    #   port = 9000
    #}

}
```

To set the port in dev mode you have to stick with the setting in `build.sbt` [RP-](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40119695/810109) postet.

Answer (score 6):

Latest play version(2.6.x) with sbt，you can also use

```
sbt "run 9001"
```