# Play Framework sbt-web integration without play plugin

Tags: playframework, sbt-web

[Embedding play as a library](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaEmbeddingPlay), I enabled the sbt-web plugin in my project, and have run `web-stage`, making assets copied verbatim to `target/web/stage/`. However using Play Framework's [string interpolation routing DSL](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaSirdRouter) as follows, they are not served when a matching request comes in:

```
object PlayServer extends App {
    val server = NettyServer.fromRouter() {   
      case GET(p"/public/$file*") => {
        val path = "/target/web/stage"
        Assets.at(path = path, file = file)
    }
}
```

Debugging through the play code [handling `Assets.at`](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9bf7399f1e2b53ba4a3c3405acd1b74fe96b53e6/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/controllers/Assets.scala#L439-L469), it looks like nothing brings the assets into being resources under `target/scala-2.11/classes/`, where presumably play framework is trying to load them as resources from. Running `sbt web-stage` does not take care of specifically that.

So what is missing for sbt-web managing to take care of placing the assets there? When manually placed there, the integration works!! so it seems sbt-web in its default configuration places the assets in the wrong target subdirectory as far as Play is concerned...

Please note that in `plugins.sbt` I include only the following from sbt-web, should that be enough?

```
addSbtPlugin("com.typesafe.sbt" % "sbt-web" % "latest.release")
```

Answer (score 0):

Placing the assets under `/src/main/resources/assets/` gets them copied to `target` upon running, bypassing any fancy sbt-web processing. This gets you out of the mud for basic dev.

The route needs to adapted like so:

```
case GET(p"/public/$file*") => {
  val path = "/assets"
  Assets.at(path = path, file = file)
}
```

Setting up a proper sbt-web pipeline for minification or whatever cannot ultimately be avoided, hence this is not really an answer, but it solves a certain use case using play for internally used applications.