# Play Framework not reading conf file inside VM

Tags: playframework, vagrant

I am running Play 2.4 inside a machine provisioned by Vagrant. I have the project files mounted to the VM `config.vm.synced_folder "project_src/", "/home/vagrant/project_src/"`

My play config has the the port setting to `play.server.http.port=8888` but this setting is not being picked up. Even when I start play with the conf option `run -Dconf.resource=application.conf` or any other conf file the setting is not being picked up.

The perm on the file is `-rw-r--r-- 1 vagrant vagrant application.conf` so I'm pretty sure that is not the issue either.

The only way I can set the port is with `-Dhttp.port=8888` which is fine but there are other env settings I'd like to read from the conf file.

Any suggestions?

Comment: According to this setting the port in `application.conf` is Play 1.x only: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205067/how-do-i-change-the-default-port-9000-that-play-uses-when-i-execute-the-run

Comment: It still works on 2.4 and you can also set it in the conf https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration#Server-configuration-options

Comment: @Adgezaza I have to agree with brandonhill. In production mode it's not possible to set the port via application.conf. But you can set it via `-Dhttp.port=1234`. See https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/ProductionConfiguration for more information.

Comment: @Kris how do I read it in a non prod env? `~run`? That isn't reading the conf either. Is it also only the port conf?

Comment: Yes, use `activator -Dhttp.port=1234 run`.