# Changing the Default Play Framework HTTP Port (without Using System Property)

Tags: scala, playframework, sbt

There's an oft-asked question about changing the HTTP port to which a Play application will bind. [James Ward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8206747/700420) is generally accepted as the most complete, but it involves overriding the default by setting a `http.port` system property. However, is it possible to change this default without having to manually add it to the `run` command at development time, tweak the environment, or package an override in a runtime configuration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by setting the [`playDefaultPort` key](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/9a06b9a0a6ea7d1299e61ea3c1f37a08b714297e/framework/src/sbt-plugin/src/main/scala/play/sbt/PlayImport.scala#L90), as follows:

```
import PlayKeys._
playDefaultPort := 9123
```

Afterwards, you'll be able to `run` and `testProd` without needing to remember the desired port.

This works in both development:

```
$ sbt run
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/michaelahlers/Projects/MyApp/project
[info] Set current project to MyApp (in build file:/Users/michaelahlers/Projects/MyApp/)

--- (Running the application, auto-reloading is enabled) ---

[info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9123

(Server started, use Ctrl+D to stop and go back to the console...)
```

And production modes:

```
$ sbt testProd
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/michaelahlers/Projects/MyApp/project
[info] Set current project to MyApp (in build file:/Users/michaelahlers/Projects/MyApp/)
[info] Packaging /Users/michaelahlers/Projects/MyApp/target/scala-2.11/MyApp_2.11-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT-web-assets.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.

(Starting server. Type Ctrl+D to exit logs, the server will remain in background)

2016-04-08 13:09:45,594 [info] a.e.s.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
2016-04-08 13:09:45,655 [info] play.api.Play - Application started (Prod)
2016-04-08 13:09:45,767 [info] p.c.s.NettyServer - Listening for HTTP on /0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:9123
```