# Change default port number Play Framework : Using the SBT assembly plugin deployment option

Tags: playframework

I already found [How do I change the default port (9000) that Play uses when I execute the "run" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205067/how-do-i-change-the-default-port-9000-that-play-uses-when-i-execute-the-run)

But it has no answer to this.

This is specific to https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/Deploying#Using-the-SBT-assembly-plugin

How can I change port when using assembly deployment option ?

I'm using

proc = new ProcessBuilder(

```
  "java",

  "-jar",

  "./lib/mode-assembley.jar",

  "-Dhttp.port=1234",

  "-Dplay.crypto.secret=abcdefghijk"



  ).start();
```

but this is still trying 9000 ! and getting

> Bad root server path:
>   /Users/xxxx/project/-Dhttp.port=1234

Answer (score 1):

I think you're better off running your jar with the java parameter

```
java -jar ... -Dhttp.port=1234
```

Or alternatively (and my preferred approach), use different configuration files per environment.

So, in development mode you run:

```
sbt -Dconfig.resource=application.dev.conf run
```

And in the file `conf/application.dev.conf` have all the configuration you want for the development mode. Then in the `conf/application.conf` you can have the production configuration.

Remember that you can compose those files. So, write them like this:

#### conf/application.conf

```
# the assembly command will take this one.
http.port=9000
```

#### conf/application.dev.conf

```
include "application.conf"

#override configuration parameters here for dev mode.
http.port=1234
```

This way, when you do the assembly, you don't need to worry about it, since it takes by default the `conf/application.conf` file, the other one will be ignored unless you launch the jar with the parameter of course.

```
java -jar -Dconfig.resource=application.dev.conf
```

Or *finally* override anything with the java parameter

```
java -jar -Dconfig.resource=application.dev.conf -Dhttp.port=4321
```

This last one, will launch the app with the dev mode configuration and also overrides the port.

Comment: In the play `application.conf`, you nee to add `play.server.http.port`.