# Ho to pass command line arguments to Play 1.x?

Tags: playframework, parameter-passing, command-line-interface

How do I pass command-line arguments when starting Play 1.x?
I've found [an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8205067/how-do-i-change-the-default-port-9000-that-play-uses-when-i-execute-the-run?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) for selecting an HTTP port or a framework ID, but not for a custom argument.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Passing arguments to Play 1.x is not possible.
You should use JVM custom arguments instead, with a `-D` annotation before the property:

```
play run -Dbla_bla_enabled=true
```

In your Java code, treat it as a string value:

```
if(System.getProperty("bla_bla_enabled").equals("true")){
   ...
}
```

Oh, and remember to check for `null` if the property might be absent.